# Sharing data between two iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and here is my scenario:

App1: Pulls data from a network (private network, connected via Wi-Fi, no access to internet) and I want to store it in a file or database.

App2: Needs to access the file/database.

Since, I can't use iCloud, what are the other solutions? Does App group work for this?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are pretty limited in terms of options, as the sandboxing of iOS apps.  You can't share the data in CoreData between two apps in a common app group.

What you could do is store the data in a shared `NSUserDefaults`.  However, depending on the size of data being shared, it may not work really well. If the data is not too massive, it is very easy to implement.

If you are downloading a large file, you could save the file and then pass it to App 2 from App 1 using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to pass the whole file to App 2.  App 2 would then have to process the data for use.  This would work for larger data, but the user experience leaves much to be desired.

You have some other options around Custom URL schemes, using the Pasteboard, etc. but passing large amounts of data between apps isn't a great experience on iOS.

Here's a good breakdown of options for sharing data: http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/.

Is there a reason why you couldn't just have App 2 also pull from the same private server that App 1 pulls from? I know it's duplicating data stored on the device, but it seems like passing that data back and forth (if App 2 can update data) and managing that would be more work than creating a common framework for both apps to pull data from the server.